# How to generate a build artifact in Azure Devops through Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-artifacts

I would need to have a build definition totally included inside a powershell script.

I can install dotnet, restore packages, build everything, and now I need to create an artifact.

I cannot find a way to call in Powershell the equivalent of the task PublishBuildArtifacts@1, nothing comes up also googling everywhere. It shouldn't be difficult...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found it, finally: I will try it using this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/create?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1

Comment: No, I didn't solve my problem, because using this interface is very complex, and I have to create full artifact definition. In the task it's much easier, so I'm still in search of the simple solution of calling that task... :-(

Answer (score 0):

'Publish build artifacts' should solve it.
I would also add a task to archive the files to be considered artifacts before the publish.

The build report now shows a link to download the files produced by the powershell script.

Summary:
**Archive task** to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip`
**Publish Build Artifacts task** publishing `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

---

yaml for the archive:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive output'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: Deliver

yaml for the publish:
- task: `PublishBuildArtifacts@1`
  displayName: '`Publish Artifact: drop`'